# Switch off highlighting "event" keyword in Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have question: How to switch off highlight keyword "event" in Visual C++ 2010? I don't use .net , so for me it isn't keyword, and I would call it one variable "event".

Answer (score 9):

This is a side-effect of the C++/CLI language supported by the IDE.  Where *event* is a keyword.  There are others, like gcnew, generic, array, etc.  Syntax highlighting is based on the file name extension and C++/CLI also uses .cpp.

I can't think of an easy fix.  I'd recommend you post feedback to connect.microsoft.com

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately there is no way to do this.  This is hard coded to be a keyword in Visual Studio's C++ editor and cannot be changed.  It's the equivalent of saying "Please stop highlighting class"

Comment: +1 iff s/in C++/in Visual Studio/. `event` is not a C++ keyword.

Comment: @Billy, updated it to be more clear that it's Visual Studio's C++ editor that considers it a keyword (not the C++ language)

Comment: ...nonetheless, you can tell other editors (eg: emacs, codewright, etc.) to quit highlighting any keyword you want with a little effort.

Comment: Unfortunately this insane diversion from standard makes studying some Qt code harder because debugger does not show the event content on mouse hover. Even if Visual Assist can be used to (maybe) remove the highlight I am not sure debugging context can be affected.

Comment: @dashesy, you can check current value of 'event' variable using QuickWatch - right click on 'event' and select Watch or QuickWatch (at least it works in my VS2005)

Comment: For Qt, you already have Qt Creator. And, the word "event" is not highlighted if I declare a variable like `int event;`